# How to avoid display block for a particular div element using css

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

In my media query I have set tables to display: block. So now display: block applies now to all the elements of the site.  How to avoid display: block so it doesn't  apply for one particular div element.

```css
{    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th, tr{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {


 /* Force table to not be like tables anymore  */
 table, th, tbody, td, thead { 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
 }
  
#content {
 

 }
  
 }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Article Question is</h1>
  <p>Below I have table inside the article. How to avoid display block for the table below on mobile screens?</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Give `display: block;` to the only element you want to give `block`

Comment: something like this ? http://prntscr.com/c7e87y

Comment: Display: `inline`, `inline-block`, `none`, `flex`, `initial`, `inherit`, umm many more, pick one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {

 /* Force table to not be like tables anymore  */
    table, th, tbody, td, thead { 
        display: block; 
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content table, #content th, #content tbody, #content td, #content thead {
        display: initial;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kodie Grantham  display: initial; worked well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to avoid just that #content table.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {


 /* Force table to not be like tables anymore  */
    table:not(#content table),
    th:not(#content th),
    tbody:not(#content tbody),
    td:not(#content td),
    thead:not(#content thead) { 
        display: block; 
        width: 100%;
    }

#content {


    }

 }
```

Either this or @KodieGrantham's solution *should* work; which one is probably a matter of preference.

Comment: Yes this one also fixed the issue @Nick Barth!